# why Ng Repeat is not working if button invoked from a different form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsp, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a html table that contains an ng repeat directive and two button.The first one will open a modal that contains a new form and let me create my user and then when i click save it will add it to the list.The second one is in the same original form and do the add a user.

What i did not understand why when i click on the first button which is in a different form i can not update the ng repeat however for the second one it's possible.
This is the code:

homepage.jsp

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="generic-container" ng-controller="UserController as ctrl">
        <div id="createUserContent.jsp" ng-include="createUserContent"></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                    ng-click="ctrl.openCreateUser()">Create</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th width="20%"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="u in ctrl.users">
                    <td><span ng-bind="u.ssoId"></span></td>
                    <td><span ng-bind="u.firstName"></span></td>
                    <td><span ng-bind="u.lastName"></span></td>
                    <td><span ng-bind="u.email"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

user_controller.js

```
'use strict';

App.controller('UserController', function ($scope, UserService, $window, $log, $uibModalStack,
        $uibModal, $rootScope) {
    var self = this;

    self.users = [];

    self.fetchAllUsers = function () {
        console.log('----------Start Printing users----------');
        for (var i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++) {
            console.log('FirstName ' + self.users[i].firstName);
        }
    };
        /**
    this function will not work
    **/
    self.saveUser = function (user) {
        self.users.push(user);
        self.fetchAllUsers();
        $log.log("saving user");
        $uibModalStack.dismissAll();
    };

    /**
    this function works fine
    **/
    self.addNewRow = function () {
        var specialUser = {
                id : 12,
                firstName : 'john',
                lastName: 'travolta',
                homeAddress : {location:'chicago'},
                email : 'trav@email.com'
        };
        self.users.push(specialUser);
        $log.log("saving specialUser");
    };
    self.openCreateUser = function () {

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation : true,
                templateUrl : 'createUserContent',
                controller : 'UserController',
                resolve : {
                    items : function () {
                        return $scope.items;
                    }
                }
            });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
    self.fetchAllUsers();
});
```

createUserContent.jsp

```
<form role="form" ng-controller="UserController as ctrl" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label> <input type="FirstName"
            ng-model="ctrl.user.firstName" class="form-control"
            id="FirstName" placeholder="Enter FirstName" /> <label
            for="lastName">lastName</label> <input type="lastName"
            class="form-control" id="lastName"
            ng-model="ctrl.user.lastName" placeholder="Enter lastName" />
        <label for="email">Email address</label> <input type="email"
            ng-model="ctrl.user.email" class="form-control" id="email"
            placeholder="Enter email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="homeAddressLocation">Home Address</label> <input class="form-control"
            ng-model="ctrl.user.homeAddress.location" id="homeAddressLocation"
            placeholder="homeAddressLocation" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="SSOId">SSOId</label> <input class="form-control"
            ng-model="ctrl.user.ssoId" id="SSOId" placeholder="SSOId" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
        ng-click="ctrl.saveUser(ctrl.user)">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because of your modal template can't access your `UserController` object and doesn't show error because you used in modal template same *controlle*r so reloaded as new `Ctrl` doesn't refer parent `Ctrl`.

However better to use different *controller* and pass parent *controller* object to modal *controller* and then modal body can use all parent object. so you should pass parent object to modal *controller*.

When you include `createUserContent.jsp` popup file in your main file then no need to use `ng-controller="UserController as ctrl"` in your modal template you used in modalInstance `controller : 'Ctrl',`

like:

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'createUserContent.jsp',
      controller: 'ModalCtrl', // ModalCtrl for modal
      controllerAs:'modal', // as modal so no need to use in modal template
      size: 'lg',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        },
        parent: function(){ // pass self object as a parent to 'ModalCtrl'
                return self;
        }
      }
```

and `ModalCtrl` like:

```
.controller('ModalCtrl', ['parent', function (parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}]);
```

here used `ModalCtrl` for modal as `modal` so you can access parent object like: `modal.parent.user`

template like:

```
<form role="form" >
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label> <input type="FirstName"
ng-model="modal.parent.user.firstName" class="form-control"
id="FirstName" placeholder="Enter FirstName" />
        .....
        ....
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
ng-click="modal.parent.saveUser(modal.parent.user)">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </form>
```

More details [Visit PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ssz1tghgcWVZfNWXzF8A?p=info)

Comment: just one word perfect :)

Comment: You are welcome and can accept my solution if it helped you  :) @BenMansourNizar